# Is it possible to get em units to behave consistently across elements with different font-size

Tags: css, responsive-design

I often find myself trying to align two different sized lines of text. Basically, trying to get the line height to stay the same even when the text size is different. This can be tricky when using `em`s as units for things like `line-height` because it references the `em` size of that particular element. Sizing `line-height` in `px` makes it easy, but it introduces other problems when trying to design responsively.

In the following examples, assume the `BIG TEXT` on the left is an `<h1>` or something set to have a larger relative `font-size` like 200% while the `small text` is something smaller like an  with `font-size:150%`.

**BAD:**

```
______________________       _______________________

                             small text with 2em lin
BIG TEXT WITH 2em LINE       _______________________
______________________
```

(This doesn't work because 2 x 200% ems is not the same as 2 x 150% ems)

**GOOD** (but not responsive)

```
______________________       _______________________


BIG TEXT WITH 40px LINE      small text with 40px line 
______________________       _______________________
```

This works because px units don't care about the size of the text, but this also introduces a problem if you want to do things like shrink the font-size on smaller screens with a media query. You then have to manage the line-height as well because the leading will be fixed regardless of whether the text changes size. Also it just gets confusing on big projects to have `px` thrown in among `em` units.

Is there a better way solve this problem that doesn't require fixed `px` units?

PS: I phrased the question in terms of `em` but the same issue happens with `%` also because it references the current element's size rather than the parent's.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 brings in a new feature which looks like exactly what you want. A new unit called `rem` which stands for 'root em', it represents an `em` at the root level of the document so it will be the same across all elements.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kyvE/)

HTML

```
<div class="eg large">Some large text</div>
<div class="eg small">Some large text</div>
```

CSS

```
.eg {
    float:left;
}

.large {
    font-size:3em;
    line-height:4rem;
}

.small {
    font-size:1.5em;
    line-height:4rem;
}
```

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/less-mixin-for-rem-font-sizing/) suggests a strategy for backwards compatibility (IE8 and below), basically just providing an approximate `px` value rule in addition to the `rem` rule.

Comment: The `rem` unit means the font size of the root element (the `html` element in an HTML document), not the parent element’s font size.

Comment: As it stated in the answer. Child elements are automatically set to the parent's font-size without setting it.

Comment: Being the font size of the root element, the `rem` unit is not an answer to the question. Child elements do not inherit parent’s font size if they have any `font-size` setting in any style sheet being applied.

Comment: Explain why the font-size of the root element would not be ideal, it allows sizing of the element based on the page's baseline font-size. As far as I'm understanding the question (center two different sized pieces of text vertically in a responsive way) it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I think we're getting into semantics that can really only be confirmed by @Emerson

Comment: The question title is “Is it possible to reference an parent element's font-size when using em units”. There was no question about centering in the question body either, only about getting the same line height.

Comment: @Tyriar has provided a useful solution to the problem. My use of the word "parent" in my question title was ambiguous and I'll change it momentarily. The heart the problem is the way `em`s and `%`s compound, so `rem`s appear to solve this nicely.

Comment: Yea I thought the title may have been misleading based on the question text. Good to hear.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you could define the line height.

```
.ems-text {
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.px-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: He gave this exact thing as an example of what he doesn't want as it isn't responsive. It will appear inconsistency across different devices and zoom-levels.

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to refer to the font size of the parent (except when setting `font-size`) in CSS. However, to the extent that you control all the style sheets involved, you can indirectly handle the situation.

For example, set `line-height` in `em` units (e.g., `line-height: 2.4em`) on the parent element of your “big” and “small” elements and do not set it at all on these elements, so that they will inherit the computed value. Example:

```
<style>
tr { line-height: 2.4em }
h1 { font-size: 200%; margin: 0}
.small { font-size: 150% }
h1, .small { border: solid 1px }
</style>
<table >
<tr><td><h1>BIG TEXT WITH 2em LINE</h1>
<td><div class=small>small text with 2em lin</div>
</table>
```

The value of `2.4em` means that for the `h1` element, the line height will equal 1.2 times its own font size.

Note that the baselines of text will not be aligned. This is a rather direct consequence of having different font sizes but equal line height (which is what the question asks for).

Comment: This solution relies on tables and their center vertical alignment behaviour in cells. While it is a solution to the problem, using tables will cause problems down the track in styling for smaller devices as well as it violating a level-A rule of WCAG 2.0 (1.3.1), using tables for non-tabular data.

Comment: No, the table is just a simple way to set up a demo. Vertical alignment wasn’t even asked in the question; I pointed it out as a potentially relevant side issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I see that you're using the table for demonstration purposes, but you seem to have just rephrased the question/problem.

Comment: I answered the question correctly (No, you can't) and also described workaround. What more is needed for an acceptable answer?